# Order posts by number of votes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, voting

Hi everybody long time reader, first time poster :)

I have an app with posts and I am using the gem thumbs_up ( rails v. 3.0.7) to add votes to the posts. I have implemented a wall of fame for the posts showing the top 10 posts and I just can't figure out how to sort the posts by votes ( plusminus method).

Now I am just using:

```
def wall_of_fame
@posts = Post.tally(
  {   :at_least => 1,
      :at_most => 10000,
      :limit => 10,
      :order => 'vote_count desc'
  })
```

end

and for the wall of shame:

```
def wall_of_fame
@posts = Post.tally(
  {   :at_least => 1,
      :at_most => 10000,
      :limit => 10,
      :order => 'vote_count asc'
  })
```

end

but actually I need to order the posts using the **plusminus** method and not just **vote_count**, because it just shows me some posts, not the ones with the most up votes, or at least something like:

```
:order => 'votes_for asc'
```

and for the wall_of_shame

```
:order => 'votes_against asc'
```

Currently votes_for and votes_against can be used only in the views like

```
@post.votes_for
```

How can I use them in my posts controller to be able to use them in **:order =>**  ?

Thank you.

Comment: Well I added votes_plus and votes_minus to the posts table and made the vote_up action to add +1 to them too. So if a user votes for a post he also adds +1 vote to the post table itself. It's not the best way to do it but it works now ;)

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue as well, but I built my voting machinery from scratch.  I ended up sorting my posts in the views.  So, I redered them like this:

```
<%= render @posts.sort_by { |post| post.votes.size }.reverse %>
```

This ordered my posts from the most votes to the least votes.

Good Luck!

@thatdankent

Comment: Wow, Been trying to figure this out for the past hour, this is way easier than I imagined.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to order plusminus:

http://gistpages.com/2013/08/28/order_by_votes_using_the_thumbs_up_gem

```
Design.plusminus_tally.order('plusminus_tally DESC')
```